# How to setup Pootle tranlation server on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to setup Pootle translation service on Ubuntu.
Unfortunately I'm stuck at running the Pootle server.

I have setup all the required software packages (pootle, translate-toolkit and others) manually.
Then if I run ./PootleServer from the installation directory it runs flawlessly.

```
/usr/src/Pootle-2.1.5# ./PootleServer
Starting server, listening on port 8080.
2011-03-14 21:53:56,001 INFO Starting Django server, listening on port 8080
```

But when I'm trying to run PootleServer with "PootleServer" command I get the following error.
Obviously Pootle expects /usr/share/pootle directory to exist, and it is NOT.
/usr/share/pootle is missing.
Do you know why?

```
/usr/src/Pootle-2.1.5# PootleServer
Starting server, listening on port 8080.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/PootleServer", line 32, in <module>
    PootleServer.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pootle/PootleServer.py", line 103, in main
    run_pootle(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pootle/PootleServer.py", line 87, in run_pootle
    handler = AdminMediaHandler(WSGIHandler(), path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.media_url = settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 73, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pootle/settings.py", line 200, in <module>
    LANGUAGES = override.find_languages(LOCALE_PATHS[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pootle/i18n/override.py", line 38, in find_languages
    dirs = os.listdir(locale_path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/pootle/mo'
```

I was not able to overcome this error.
Please help me to setup PootleServer properly.

Installed software

```
/usr/src/Pootle-2.1.5# PootleServer --version
Pootle 2.1.5
Translate Toolkit 1.8.1
Django 1.2.5
```

Ubuntu 9.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `mo` directory you're missing there is the same `mo` directory referenced [here](http://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/translate/src/trunk/Pootle/mo/README?revision=12417&view=markup), which suggests that `setup.py` has a `build_mo` command.

That said, it appears that the rest of pootle was installed using a PREFIX of `/usr/local`, so it's likely that the mo directory is somewhere like `/usr/local/share/pootle/mo` and you'll need to track down the configuration and fix it, or if there is no configuration, file a bug against the project to obey the installation PREFIX if you install somewhere other than the default (and move the folder to `/usr/share`).

Comment: Derf, thank you so much. I have moved /usr/share/pootle to /usr/local/pootle and PootleServer has launched flawlessly!